# Polulate Select Box with Json Ajax response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a json array returned from an Ajax request that look like below.

```
{
  "success":true,
  "message":null,
  "messages":null,
  "data":[
    {"Type":"Model","Value":"A Model"},
    {"Type":"Model","Value":"B Model"}
  ]
}
```

I would like to grab each data and make it a option in a select box. However the jquery code is not working. Thanks for your help.

```
$.each(response.data, function(key, val){
   $('#mySelect').append('<option id="' + val.Value + '">' +   val.Value + '</option>');
})
```

Comment: Missing `+` between `val.Value '</option>'`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var response = {
  "success":true,
  "message":null,
  "messages":null,
  "data":[
    {"Type":"Model","Value":"A Model"},
    {"Type":"Model","Value":"B Model"}
  ]
}

$.each(response.data, function(key, val){
   $('select').append('<option id="' + val.Value + '">' +   val.Value +'</option>');//missing +
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Comment: I fixed the missing + but still the select is not being populated. when I do alert(response.data) I get an undefined message

Comment: Nothing, the select box stays empty

Comment: @user1709251 check the id of the select are sure you append to the correct select